# How to use mongodb in Spring roo project?

Tags: jpa, spring-roo, datanucleus

In Spring Roo when we enable our project for JPA using the following command:-

```
jpa setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database
```

Then I found that there is no option for MongoDB after --database option.So i want to know how can I do it.

I am thinking to create a JPA setup for MySql and then make changes in the generated persistence.xml for MongoDB cause at the end even ROO is a java project.But I don't know whether its the correct approach.

I would appreciate any assistance in doing this.Any link or example will be great.

Answer (score 5):

There is a similar Roo command for MongoDB:

```
roo> mongo setup
```

and to create entities:

```
roo> entity mongo --class ~.domain.Pizza
```

Find more details at this URL: http://blog.springsource.org/2011/09/14/new-application-layering-and-persistence-choices-in-spring-roo/

Comment: I need Datanucleus +MongoDB setup.

Answer (score 1):

```
mongo setup --databaseName personDB
entity mongo --class ~.model.Person --testAutomatically
field string --fieldName name --notNull
repository mongo --interface ~.repository.PersonRepository --entity ~.model.Person
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA is JPA regardless of the datastore. Just set the datastore to a "Spring-supported" db and then update persistence.xml as you say. DataNucleus support for MongoDB will ignore the annotations that are inapplicable for a particular datastore (as per the DN docs and supported features page)

Comment: I tried to do the above and made changes to persistence.xml.
`<property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="mongodb:localhost/mng1"/>  
            <property name="datanucleus.storeManagerType" value="mongodb" />  
            <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true" />`

But When I run the program it gives me error that can not resolve bean EntityManager in application.xml.What to do now.

My work requires SpringROO+Datanucleus+MongoDB setup.How to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you haven't resolved some Spring bean then you need to update your Spring config to resolve it ... and have datanucleus-api-jpa in the CLASSPATH (since that has the EntityManager). That's all there is